# ERROR: invalid value for "MI" Detail: Value must be an integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-aurora, sql-timestamp, to-timestamp

In PostgreSQL, I got an error for the following request:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-07T22:34:18Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ');
```

which yielded:

> ERROR: invalid value ":1" for "MI" Detail: Value must be an integer.

Why there would be an error specifically at ":1" and not before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres 12 works with your query as posted, 9.4 gives the error you state because it is interpreting `DDTH` as "day with letters after" like `1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th` i.e. `Nth`

So.. the parser will consume the day `07` and then the next two chars and toss them away (`T2` are tossed), then it looks at the next thing in your format string, which is `H24:` - this is not a recognisable placeholder for anything, so it skips 4 chars from the input too, before it gets to `MI` which it recognises, but by now `:1` from the `:18` is in position to be parsed. See the comment below:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(
  '2020-03-07T22:34:18Z', 
-- YEARsMOsDAYNssssMI
  'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI');

Key: YEAR/MO/DAYN - recognised things
     s - skipped things
```

To ignore the T , use a space, not a `T` literal in the format string:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-07T22:34:18Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Actually, you can use pretty much anything else that will ordinarily be skipped too

Answer (score 3):

Just surround the litteral `T` with double quotes:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-07"T"22:34:18Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ');
```

**[Reference: Postgres formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)**:

> In `to_date`, `to_number`, and `to_timestamp`, literal text and double-quoted strings result in skipping the number of characters contained in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is well formatted for a timestamp, so you can just convert it:

```
select '2020-03-07T22:34:18Z'::timestamp
```